# Where should I create my development blog?

Tags: c#, asp.net, blogs

I'm looking for a blogging site to host my ASP.Net/C# (and possibly other web related programming) technical blog - where should I create such blog?

BTW, it's a shame that SO does not offer blogging services.

*Note: I would create it on http://weblogs.asp.net, but it requires to be a highly active member on their site.*

Comment: SO doesn't offer blogging services for the same reason that car manufacturers don't fit TV screens in their cars' steering wheels.

Comment: @APC Would a community built around SO wiht blogs and articles be so bad? I think it could be a great idea to built a blog system with a voting system like SO.

Comment: Start a blog.  Put the URL in your profile.  If your questions and answers are sufficiently arresting people will read your profile and click through to read more of your incisive ideas couched in your deathless prose.  Says the man who hasn't blogged in almost nine months....

Comment: @APC, you're absolutely right. I guess those poor souls from  http://www.asp.net/ will regret the day they allowed such blogs to be created (http://weblogs.asp.net/scottgu/) ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would personally suggest WordPress if you'd like to get up and running quickly. I am sure a thousand people have a thousand different opinions on what is good and what isn't. I like WordPress because the templates are easy, there are some nice features, they will give you your content in XML form for backup or moving to another service in the future and it links well with LinkedIn and other services to share your posts and drive in traffic.

Answer (score 2):

WordPress, Drupal and Joomla are all good choices for running a blog if you choose to use a dedicated hosting service (e.g. hostclear, etc.), and they're all extremely well supported by  their dedicated community.

Here's a good article which offers a high level comparison of the three:
http://www.goodwebpractices.com/other/wordpress-vs-joomla-vs-drupal.html

Speaking from personal experience, I think it's worth getting a decent hosting service like HostClear, they're pretty cheap these days and gives you domain registration for free too. I've been running my blog for about 8 months now, at less than £3 a month and I've been more than happy with the service I got! And having tried both Joomla and WordPress, I found WordPress much easier to get started with.

Answer (score 0):

Toolbox.com is a great site.  They have over a million members, so the audience is built in, and they have a revenue sharing program.